# How to export classes/models that are not components,directives or pipes in an Angular 4 Module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-modules

I understand how I create a module with components, directives, pipes, export and then import them in another angular module. It works fine.

But suppose I have a generic module 'GenericCarList', which has a component
that can received info to build a beautiful car list with usefull informations, so, I can define my module as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GenericCarListComponent } from './genericCarList.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    GenericCarListComponent 
  ],
  exports: [
    GenericCarListComponent
]
})
export class GenericCarListModule{ }
```

So, above I'm declaring GenericCarListModule and exporting GenericCarListComponent to be used by other module that uses GenericCarListModule.

In another project which has a AppModule, I can import GenericCarListModule and use GenericCarListComponent just adding the following tag in my html file:

```
<app-genericCarListComponent>My generic Car List</app-genericCarListComponent>
```

after importing my GenericCarListComponent

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { GenericCarListComponent } from '....'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GenericCarListComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It works fine! :)

But I would like to have in my GenericCarListModule useful classes and models. For example:

```
//a car model
//car.ts

export class car {
    maxSpeed: number;
    color: string;

}
```

and

```
//a car commons class
    //carCommons.ts

export class carCommons {

    //some useful methods that is useful for anyone that is using this list car module.

}
```

If they were components, pipes or directives, I could export them like I did previously:

```
 exports: [
        GenericCarListComponent
    ]
```

In Angular Docs, they say:

> What should I export?
>
> Export declarable classes that components in other NgModules are able
>   to reference in their templates. These are your public classes. If you
>   don't export a class, it stays private, visible only to other
>   component declared in this NgModule.
>
> You can export any declarable class—components, directives, and
>   pipes—whether it's declared in this NgModule or in an imported
>   NgModule.

As they're not declarable class—components, directives, and pipes, how is the proper way to export and then import theses classes in my AppModule?

Comment: Use real modules for that. `NgModule`s are an awful thing in first place, be glad you don't have to use them for everything.

Comment: you don't need to declare those things in app module, you can just import them with an import statement and use as needed in your other components / directives / pipes / services.  Module imports / declarations are only for things that angular needs to parse in templates and register with the injector, so components, directives and pipes, providers are for things that need to be registered with the injector, so services.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you mean that I should have an NgModule with GenericCarListComponent and an normal typescript module with my car model and carCommons  classes? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Also ES Modules are good enough for frameworks like React, Aurelia, Vue, and Ember, but Angular decided to be special and confuse everyone with their own, non-orthogonal and opaque module concept (introduced in Angular 2.0-beta-rc.5...). Now you have to use both to learn their framework. But ES Modules (what you are calling TS Modules) are fundamental to the language, deeper than the framework.

Comment: I love the phrasing from the docs: "Export declarable classes"`